# Why can't we group together same dataype arguments in function parameter list?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I wonder why can't we group together the variables of same datatype in a function argument list ???

i.e.

Why can't be this prototype:

```
int func (int a, int b, int c, const char ch1, const char ch2);
```

be written like this:

```
int func (int a, b, c, const char ch1, ch2);
```

???

It would save time and space both, IMHO.

Comment: Because that's how the language is specified? And it's also much easier when reading the argument list to distinguish between parameters. And also much easier to write compilers as well.

Comment: Start to write it in assembly language and rewrite the compiler and linker for the c++ language and there you go!

Comment: You probably shouldn't have large number of parameters of the same type, so there is no reason to make that easier.

Comment: If you add the definitions `typedef std::string b; typedef float c; struct ch2{};` your second example compiles. Do you still think it's a good idea?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah it makes sense now. Its strange, it seems obvious now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Don't ever give such answers man....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A molbdnilo says in the comment, the compiler needs to be able to tell the difference between a type name and an argument name. The syntax of `Type [ArgName] {, Type ArgName }` allows the compiler to first look for a type specifier, and an optional argument name. If you do it in the way that your post describes, there is no simple way for the compiler to determine if `b` and `c` are supposed to be type names or argument names - and since you are allowed to do things like:

```
typedef int foo;
int func(int x, int foo) { ... }
```

(even if that is a BAD idea), it's not possible for the compiler to say "ah, it's the name of a type, so can't be a variable name" - only the argument name's relative position is telling the compiler how to interpret that.

Note that for prototypes, it's perfectly valid to do:

```
  int func(int, int, double, int, char);
```

or

```
  int func(int x, int y, double, int z, char);
```

(This can also be used if the `double` and `char` argument isn't used in this particular function, but the function is part of an interface, where these arguments are always present, so you need to tell the compiler that they are there)

When designing a language it's very important to make sure that the compiler can understand what you mean, so having a syntax that could mean two different things depending on something "the compiler has to guess", then it would cause interesting challenges for the programmer to know what it actually does.